# Logic question: simplifying expression

Tags: logic

So I have to negate and simplify this:

p∧(q∨r)∧(~p∨~q∨r)
...
I simplified all the way to this:

[~p∨(q∧~r)]∨(~q∧~r)

what do I do from here?

The last result should be ~p∨~r

Comment: $(q\land \lnot r)\lor (\lnot q\land \lnot r)$ is logically equivalent to $\lnot r$.

Comment: what someone else did was ~p∨[(~q∨q)∧~r] which lead to ~p∨~r but I fail to see what happened

Answer (score 0):

A different approach:

We define Boolean variables $p,q,r \in \{0,1\}$. We write $p'$ for $\lnot p$, and also write $p'=1-p$.

We assume the logic operators $\lor$ and $\land$ are associative and distributive, at least for this case, and they obey the normal rules. We use multiplication for $\land$ and addition for $\lor$.

So, we can write your expression as:

$$p(q+r)(p'+q'+r)$$

Expanding we get:

$$pqp'+pqq'+pqr+prp'+prq'+prr$$

Now anything with $pp'$ or similar is false, i.e. it will evaluate to $0$. So we get:

$$pqr+prq'+prr$$

Also $q'=1-q, rr=r$ so:

$$pqr+pr(1-q)+pr=pqr+pr-pqr+pr=2pr$$

A claim, $2pr=pr$, so your expression is simplified to $pr=p\land r$. Negating gives $\lnot(p\land r)\equiv (\lnot p \lor \lnot r)$

[Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify%20p%20and%20%28q%20or%20r%29%20and%20%28not%20p%20or%20not%20q%20or%20r%29) justifies this, and the [truth table](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=truth+table+p+and+%28q+or+r%29+and+%28not+p+or+not+q+or+r%29).

Everything seems okay except for maybe the algebra and $2pr=pr$.

I did manage a version of De Morgan's laws in that $(pq)'+p'q'=p'+q'$, which we can see as:
$$(pq)'+p'q'\\=(1-pq)+(1-p)(1-q)\\=1-pq+1-p-q+pq\\=2-p-q\\=(1-p)+(1-q)\\=p'+q'$$.

You probably won't like this, but I tried. I can't see insurmountable errors with it...

APPENDUM:

Also $(p+q)'+pq=1-p-q+pq=(1-p)(1-q)=p'q'$

And therefore $(pq)'+(p+q)'+pq=p'+q'$.

$\lnot(p\land q)\lor\lnot(p\lor q)\lor(p\land q)\equiv\lnot p\lor\lnot q$.